# How do I make this Hover effect on a Card component?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I want to make a hover effect over a Card component that shows more information but I tried a lot of codepen's and videos but it doesn't work for me.

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import '../styles/Project.css'

class Project extends Component {
  render() {
return (
  <div className="Project-card">
    <img
      className="Project-card-image"
      src={this.props.image}
      alt={this.props.title}
    />
  <div className="display-over">
    <div className="Project-card-libraries">
      {this.props.libraries.map((prop) => (
        <img
          src={prop.image}
          alt={prop.name}
          className="Project-card-library-images"
        />
    ))}
    </div>
 </div>
  </div>
  )
 }
}
```

```css
.Project-card {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
  width: 60%;
  height: 100%;
    border-radius: 1em;
    margin-top: 1em;
    align-self: center;
    border-radius: 15px;
    transition: 0.4s ease-out;
  box-shadow: 0px 7px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  position: relative;
}

.display-over {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  color: #fff;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.Project-card:hover .display-over {
  opacity: 1;
}

.Project-card-image {
    width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  border-radius: 15px;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VX4PA.png) I want the red container to be over the whole green container.
[I have this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KOTH3.png). I don't want that white space there which is the div with classname - display-over.
I need that content to be displayed over the image.

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow ! Could you explain in your question what is not working with your code so other people can help you?

Comment: @ChristopheLeBesnerais I edited the question. I have 2 photos which I hope explains better what I want. If I still have to add any more info please let me know.

Comment: @Marius do you want the red content to be displayed on hover or when do you want it to be displayed

Comment: @PascalNitcheu yes. the red container I want to be displayed while I hover on the green container. And I also don't want that white space to be displayed.

Comment: @Marius What do you want to have on the White place when the user is not hovering ? Also on your Form are you using a button component for the create Account function or a form ?

Comment: @PascalNitcheu that white space I want to not be displayed. That form is just an image from a project I've made. I'm working on a portfolio website, and those are preview Cards (hope it makes sense)